# Run two function at the same time without delay Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make an app which will record sound from mic while doing countdown(and show the time left on window) at the same time. I have tried both `multiprocessing` and `threading` module but the window that show countdown and recording(called from module record.py) won't run at the same time.
Can anyone suggest any way that can do it?
Thanks in advance.

Below is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import record as rc    #record.py is the module to record sound from mic

PRACTICETIME=120

class App(tk.Tk):   
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self,"PreSys")

        self.container = tk.Frame(self, height = 1000, width =1000)
        self.container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        self.container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        self.create_practicePage(PracticePage)


    def create_practicePage(self,cont):
        frame = PracticePage(self.container, self)
        self.frames[PracticePage] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(PracticePage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()  



class PracticePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.timeLeft = tk.Label(self,text= "")

        self.timeLeft.pack()

        self.remaining = 0
        self.countdown(120)
        rc.start_record()    #function to record sound


    def countdown(self, remaining = None):
        if remaining is not None:
            self.remaining = remaining

        if self.remaining <= 0:
            self.timeLeft.configure(text="お疲れ様です！")
        else:
            mins, secs = divmod(self.remaining,60)
            mins = round(mins)
            secs = round(secs)
            self.timeLeft.configure(text=str(mins) +"分"+ str(secs) +"秒")
            self.remaining = self.remaining - 1
            self.after(1000, self.countdown)

apps = App()
apps.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try changing `rc.start_record()` to `threading.Thread(target=rc.start_record).start()`.

Comment: It is not quite that simple @acw1668. Yes they need to use threading but they will need to do more than the change you mentioned.

Comment: I have tried threading, but delay still happens where the countdown window shows only after the recording finished.

Comment: Are you using threading inside `rc.start_record()`?  Did you call thread's `join()`?  If yes, the `join()` function will block the main thread until it finishes.